# Intellij Idea Autocomplete not working for flutter and Java

Tags: java, android, flutter, intellij-idea, autocomplete

I'm currently using intellij idea 2020.3.1 . I have done many mini projects with java and flutter and i have never faced any problem with the autocomplete feature/intellisense before until now. It just suddenly stopped working and i have been trying to fix it for days. I have tried the following solutions to no avail.

1. Disable the power mode off
2. I have marked my project root directory as the sources root
3. I set up my JDK correctly
4. I have done the "invalidate caches/restart"

All to no avail. Is there anything else i could do, please?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YcTK.png)

Comment: Are there any errors/warnings in idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...")?

Comment: No, there were no warnings in idea.log

Answer (score 2):

After much research on the internet, i found out that the problem was from Settings|Editor|Code Completion|Show the documentation popup , was unchecked. How it became unchecked(I cant remember doing it), i dont really know. After i checked it, the code completion feature started working